# Converting same date on my database and html

Tags: php, html, mysql

good day! i am a newbie in php and i have something to ask.
I have a database fieldname date_reserved which is the date format is ex. June-12-2015.
My problem is I can't convert my html code on the same format like whats inside my database. when i tried to echo them the result is 2015-01-06.

Here is my html code.

```
<?php 
            if(isset($_GET['cancel_button']))
            {

                $REuntil = date_create(strip_tags($_GET['until']));
                $REfrom = date_create(strip_tags($_GET['from']));
                $until = date_format($REuntil, "F-d-Y");
                $from =  date_format($REfrom,"F-d-Y");
        ?>
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <tr>
                <td><strong>Cottage Name</strong></td>
                <td><strong>Customer Name</strong></td>
                <td><strong>Date Reserved</strong></td>
                <td><strong>Reservation Type</strong></td>
                <td><strong>Total Payment</strong></td>
            </tr>
        <?php
            $kweri = $dbcon->query("SELECT * FROM booking
                    INNER JOIN cottages on cottages.cot_id = booking.cottage_id
                    LEFT JOIN members on members.cust_id = booking.customer_id
                    WHERE (date_reserved BETWEEN '$from' and '$until') and book_status = 'Canceled'") 
                or die(mysqli_error());
                while($row = $kweri->fetch_assoc())
                {

        ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $row['cot_type']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['walkin_fname']?><?php echo $row['walkin_lname']?><?php echo $row['cust_fname']?><?php echo $row['cust_lname']?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['date_reserved']?></td>
                <td>
                <div class="label label-primary"><?php if($row['customer_id'] == '0'): echo 'Walkin'; endif;?></div>
                <div class="label label-success"><?php if($row['customer_id'] > '0'): echo 'Online'; endif;?></div>
                </td>

            </tr>
        <?php 
                }
                echo'</table>';
            }
        ?>
```

Comment: Are you sure `June-12-2015` is correct format of date for function `date_create`?

Comment: you want to convert date to this (June-12-2015)?

Comment: yeah, in html not in my database field because if i change it my whole reservation system will not work so I will adjust my html into the same format :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

change

```
<td><?php echo $row['date_reserved']?></td>
```

to

```
<td><?php echo date('F-d-Y' ,strtotime($row['date_reserved']))?></td>
```

Comment: Hi Qaisar, I found the error now.. actually my code is working but i have a little problem is that the sorting of date is good for that month only.. try to change the $until and $from into Januray-01-2015 until December-01-2015 and query it it will not show the result.

Comment: what is value in database for date_reserved? and change the datatype to date.then you query will work